# Find distance between two points with longitude and latitude

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2014

I got an answer to this question from this website however the answer I get is wrong.

```
DECLARE @orig_lat DECIMAL
DECLARE @orig_lng DECIMAL
SET @orig_lat=52.676 set @orig_lng=-1.6193
DECLARE @orig geography = geography::Point(@orig_lat, @orig_lng, 4326);
SELECT @orig.STDistance(geography::Point(Latitude, longitude, 4326))  AS distance
From ...
```

However I get the wrong answer
e.g. distance 234229 latitude 55.0853 and longitude -1.595

I have to admit I just copied the code and Don't understand it. The answer should be 166 miles which is 267 km.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Short answer:**

Make `@orig_lat` and `@orig_lng` of type `decimal(19,6)` (for example) or `float`.

**Long answer:**

The issue is because your `decimals` have no actual decimals (you are using the default precision, which is `decimal(18,0)`), so they end up being 53 and -2. You should define their precision (e.g. `decimal(19,6)`) or just use `float`, which is the type the function expects anyway. If you simply change this, it works fine:

```
DECLARE @orig_lat float
DECLARE @orig_lng float
SET @orig_lat=52.676 set @orig_lng=-1.6193
DECLARE @orig geography = geography::Point(@orig_lat, @orig_lng, 4326);
DECLARE @dest geography = geography::Point(55.0853, -1.595, 4326);
select @orig.STDistance(@dest)
```

This returns `268166.415685712`.

I discovered this by simply printing the `varchar` equivalent of the `geography`:

```
DECLARE @orig_lat decimal
DECLARE @orig_lng decimal
SET @orig_lat=52.676 set @orig_lng=-1.6193
DECLARE @orig geography = geography::Point(@orig_lat, @orig_lng, 4326);
select cast(@orig as varchar)
```

That will print `POINT (-2 53)`, which also gives you another piece of information besides the rounding: that varchar format uses longitude-latitude instead of latitude-longitude. So if you wanted to create those points the other way, you should use:

```
DECLARE @orig geography = 'POINT(-1.6193 52.676)'
DECLARE @dest geography = 'POINT(-1.595 55.0853)'
SELECT @orig.STDistance(@dest)
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your full answer, that makes sense and is working now with the decimal places.                                                                                       The swapping around of Latitude and longitude is certainly confusing and concerning however I think https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933811.aspx says the reason is that when it is printed it is swapped around so it is like map co-ordinates.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is in meters, divide by 1000 and you have km.

I try to break it down to you:

```
-- I assume you already know that this part is only declaring variables
-- and setting them.
-- In this case they are the variables for your starting coordinates.
DECLARE @orig_lat DECIMAL
DECLARE @orig_lng DECIMAL
SET @orig_lat=52.676 set @orig_lng=-1.6193

-- MS SQL has built in geography functions 
-- like a function to determine the distance between 2 points.
-- But it uses an own unit instead of longitude/latitude: point.
-- So you have to use the geography::Point-function to convert
-- a lat/lon coordinate into a point value:
DECLARE @orig geography = geography::Point(@orig_lat, @orig_lng, 4326);

-- The rest is basically the same again with the target coordinates,
-- namely this part: geography::Point(Latitude, longitude, 4326)
-- embedded in the STDistance function. This function calculates the distance
-- between 2 point values.
SELECT @orig.STDistance(geography::Point(Latitude, Longitude, 4326)) AS distance
From ...
-- where Latitude and Longitude would be your destination coordinates.
```

If you want you can write your own statement, the mathematical background of this is the Haversine formula basically measuring the distance between 2 points on a sphere.

Comment: His code is not working. `234229 / 1000 != 267`. The issue was the variable types, as stated in my answer.

Answer (score -1):

A more simplified way is this:

```
DECLARE @source geography = 'POINT(52.676 -1.6193)'
DECLARE @target geography = 'POINT(55.0853 -1.595)'

SELECT @source.STDistance(@target)
```

Comment: That doesn't help, he has the points in a table, and besides, you are swapping longitude and latitude there.